# Does nodejs provides options like resolve.alias in webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I use resolve.alias to eliminate long relative path.

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    // ...
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            services: __dirname + '/src/services',
            components: __dirname + '/src/components'
        },
}

// componentFoo.js
import ServiceBar from 'services/serviceBar'
```

But when I tried using ava to run tests, node cannot find module 'services/serviceBar'.

My folder structure:
src
--components
----componentFoo.js
--services
----serviceBar.js
test
--index.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.js does not have any built-in option for aliases. But you can use the babel plugin [babel-plugin-module-resolver](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver) to define aliases, which should be convenient as AVA already uses babel.

You need to add it to your babel plugins:

```
"plugins": [
  ["module-resolver", {
    "alias": {
      "services": "./src/services",
      "components": "./src/components"
    }
  }]
]
```

The paths are relative to the babel config, unless you specify the `cwd` option ([list of options](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver#options)). Another possibility would be to use the `root` option instead of aliases, which is similar to webpack's [`resolve.modules`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules):

```
"root": ["./src"]
```